# tmux detach while running script

Tags: terminal, tmux

So I have a script that I would like to run on my server and not have it bother me. So I thought I would run the server in a tmux window and then `detach` it so I could simply `attach` if I ever want to look at the progress (this script will take days to run).

but when I run my script in the tmux window, I am not able to `detatch` while it is running. Is there something I am doing wrong? How can I detach while this still runs? I feel like I am being very oblivious to an obvious solution here.

Comment: What happens when you try to detach?  What you describe is a typical work flow.

Comment: my script runs and when I type `tmux detach` it does nothing and just stays there

Comment: Where do you type `tmux detach`?  Why not just do `C-b d` (or whatever you may have remapped the prefix key to, followed by `d`)

Comment: I am not familiar to what that is? And it appears to be typed in the python consol as the script has not finished running

Comment: Hmm.  You should be running `tmux` first, which will give you a shell running inside `tmux`.  Then run the script.  Then type `C-b d` (ctrl-B, followed by d).  Alternatively, run your script with a command called `dtach`. (http://dtach.sourceforge.net)

Comment: I do run tmux first and then run the script...but I will cancel and try that

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Answer (score 3):

You can detach from a `tmux` session while leaving the script running by:

`CTRL` + `b`, then pressing `d`

You can enter back into the session by running `tmux attach -t <session id>`